# Hex string vs big int index in Android Sqlite/ORMLite

Tags: android, performance, orm, sqlite, android-sqlite

We are storing a lot of hex data in our mobile devices (f.e.: "2D2134F2487B0ACE08B7"), around 600.000 to 900.000 entries.

The query for this is quite slow...

```
select id from 'combinations' where token = '2D2134F2487B0ACE08B7' limit 1
```

Would it make sense to store the token as binary number, so that the index is much faster than the string comparison?

The problem is also - is it possible to store such big binary numbers in sqlite?

```
f.e. 
hex: 2D2134F2487B0ACE08B7
=> "00101101001000010011010011110010010010000111101100001010110011100000100010110111"
```

I couldnt find anythin which i understand... :/
Thanks!

**EDIT:** LOLOL... Im not sure why I didn't realized it earlier... I could also convert the hex to normal integer, which would save a lot of key length... But anyway.. question is still if I can save big values like "213119049475094085503159" in int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What SQLite can store as `NUMBER` is defined [here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

meaning a value equivalent to `long`. The hex length is

```
    0102030405060708
```

which is not enough for

```
2D2134F2487B0ACE08B7
```

So the answer is: no you can't store that as number.

In case you haven't done so, consider to index that column, since that would speed up the query you're doing. See https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html for a pretty good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite's integers cannot have more than 64 bits.

If `token` is indexed, lookups will be fast.

To save space, you could store the values as blobs:

```
select id from combinations where token = x'2D2134F2487B0ACE08B7'
```

(SQLite indexes support all data types.)

Comment: Do you think the lookup with index is faster in blob than in string?

Comment: Hex strings use double the size, i.e., require more I/O.